# how to slant image and div in one side only in html using css

Tags: html, css, image, box, skew

i have a website, where i am trying to create a section where there are 3 columns, 1st column is a text box, second and third is an image, i want to slant the first column on right, second column left and right and third column only on left so that it will look complete. i used the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="customer-logos1 slider" style="color:white;font-weight:400">
    <div class="slide">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-4" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <div style="background:#f7f7f7;height:100%">
            <div class="tm-offer-content" style="text-align:center;padding-top:25%">

              <h4>Brand ear ring starting from </h1>
                <h6>Our popular products are so beautiful to see that the shoppers are easily attracted to them.</h4>
              <span class="badge badge-warning" style="background:#A07F3D;color:white;font-size: inherit;
        padding: 0.55em 0.8em;"> Starting From 500</span>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-4" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <img src="https://jewelit.in/admin/uploads/about/about-image.jpg" style="-ms-transform: skew(354deg,0deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(354deg,0deg);
        transform: skew(354deg,0deg);">
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-4" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <img src="https://jewelit.in/admin/uploads/about/about-image.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>


</section>
```

here the issue is when i use skew both the sides are getting slanted, how can just slant one side so i can match these columns, thanks in advance

Comment: Your snippet is not showing anything useful or functional or even the current state of your code that you are unsatisfied with as far as I can see...?

Comment: @somethinghere i dont know, i have added the bootstrap as well, all the 3 columns are in same row, first image will slant right side and middle will slant left and right which is working fine and third image will slant left side, making it look like a rectangle, but slant inside

Comment: Check your snippet and try to at least reproduce  where you got, because the current snippet tells us nothing and doesn’t help us to fix it with you.